# Why the variable is not updating after get method?

Tags: jquery, json

Why is the xyz variable not updating even after JSON is coming from the php page ?

```
var xyz = '';
$.get("filteredRestaurant.php", {dineTypeIdString: checked}, function(data) {
            var response = JSON.parse(data);
            $.each(response, function(index, value) {
                xyz += 'a '; // line 5
            });
        });
        xyz += 'b';
        $('.filteredRestBody').html(xyz);
```

Even after line 5, the xyz's value is b
Anyone, please help me out

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you mean to write `xyz` where it says `innerHtml`? If so, it's asynchronous.

Comment: sorry for the mistake, i had corrected it

Comment: @adreneo, can you please explain it

Comment: The duplicate explains it thoroughly !

Answer (score 1):

$.get is ajax call which is asynchronous, moment ajax call is in progress statement

```
xyz += 'b'; 
$('.filteredRestBody').html(xyz);
```

gets executed, while till moment after ajax call completes, try makes ajax call synchronous

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
async: false
```

for ajax

```
 $.ajax({
        async: false,
        // ...
        success: function(data) {

        }
    });
```